# TS 2339: return additional info along with the Observable<MyObject>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a web service that returns an array of objects (some abstract array of `Entry` for a given `Site`), but also the pagination data.

In Angular, I try to recuperate the data as `Observable<MyObj>`, but also the pagination data...

I have an error however linked to this

```
findEntries(
  siteId: number, filter = '', sortOrder = 'asc', sortActive= 'date',
  pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 10): Observable<Entry[]> {

  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/api/entries`, {
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('siteId', siteId.toString())
      .set('filter', filter)
      .set('sortOrder', sortOrder)
      .set('sortActive', sortActive)
      .set('pageIndex', pageIndex.toString())
      .set('pageSize', pageSize.toString()),
    observe: 'response'
  }).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      const pager = JSON.parse(res.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
      const playload: { [id: number]: Entry } = res.body;
      const array = Object.values(playload);

                   // <<<<<=== TS 2339: Property 'pager' does not exist on type 'Entry[]'
      array.pager = pager;

      return array;
    })
  );
}
```

1) how to get rid of this error, and
2) is it the correct way to deal with pagination data on the client side?

Comment: Isn't the pager data coming in as part of the headers? Isn't that what you have already defined as `const pager`? Or is it *also* provided in the body: `array.pager`?

Comment: yes, but I should return an `Observable<Entry[]>`

Comment: What is confusing about that error? Your observable is supposed to return `Entry[]`, and `array` is an array, which doesn't have a `pager` property.

Comment: yes, but I need to return as well the pager data, what is the current page...

Comment: Then you need to change what you say the observable is returning; even so, adding it as a property to the array probably isn't a great idea.

Comment: _"I should return an Observable<Entry[]>"_ and "I need to return as well the pager data" are contradictory statements. The usual way to deal with paging is something like @DeborahK suggested. With the addition that data usually comes in that form from the server.

Comment: This is actually a good/interesting question. Not sure which it has been down voted?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a second interface that better defines the shape of what you are returning:

```
export interface EntryPlus {
   entries: Entry[];
   pager: Pager
}
```

This defines the data returned by the method. You'll probably want a better name. :-)

Then change the method to return `Observable<EntryPlus>`

```
findEntries(
  siteId: number, filter = '', sortOrder = 'asc', sortActive= 'date',
  pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 10): Observable<EntryPlus> {

return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/api/entries`, {
    params: new HttpParams()
      .set('siteId', siteId.toString())
      .set('filter', filter)
      .set('sortOrder', sortOrder)
      .set('sortActive', sortActive)
      .set('pageIndex', pageIndex.toString())
      .set('pageSize', pageSize.toString()),
    observe: 'response'
  }).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      // I assume the following two lines from your original code are correct?
      const pager = JSON.parse(res.headers.get('X-Pagination'));
      const playload: { [id: number]: Entry } = res.body;

      // Map them into the EntryPlus structure
      return {
         entries: payload,
         pager: pager
      }
    })
  );

}
```

NOTE: Not syntax checked!

Then the calling code can pull the array out from the returned value. If you want to update your question with a bit of the calling code, I can provide an example.

Something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.entryService.findEntries().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.entries = data.entries;   // This is now the array you need
        this.pager = data.pager;       // This is now the pager info you need
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

This code calls the `findEntries` method and then breaks up the returned value into its two pieces: the `Entries[]` and the `pager`.

Comment: the point of an Observable Array that it observes the array members, as I understood, so if I have no anymore an array, this will broke the logic... not sure

Comment: When coming back from an Http call, it observes the *response* ... an **single** response ... not each array element. So you can just pull the array off in the calling code. If you provide an example caller, I can provide a bit more in my answer.

Comment: hello, and thanks for your answer... actually my problem is there where you put "...", I have a web service that returns a dictionary (id: EntryObj) ({`return query.ToDictionary(e => e.EntryId, e => e);`), so this is my my function map inside... could you suggest what modifications should be done in the map function (OP)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I filled in the `...`